# DirectAccess and PCI DSS

Tags: tls, vpn, pci-dss

Has anyone came across the situation if you disable TLS 1.0 to make the server PCI DSS compliance according the 3.1 specification DirectAccess breaks, it seems to only communicate with TLS 1.0 enabled.

How can I make DirectAccess communicate via TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2?

Comment: Have you read the DirectAccess documentation, and Richard Hicks' blog: https://directaccess.richardhicks.com/2014/09/23/directaccess-ip-https-ssl-and-tls-insecure-cipher-suites/

Comment: Yes I saw that one but was not too sure whether that will affect it using TLS 1.0

Comment: By the way I already disabled NULL and re-ordered the encryption ciphers. I already get an A rating but the problem is it interferes with PCI-DSS compliance if i disable TLS 1.0